# What does it mean for two datums to be navigationally equivalent?

Tags: datum, navigation

I read from [NOAA](http://www.nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/mcd/learnnc_horizdatum.html) that NAD83 and WGS84 are "navigationally equivalent"

> NOAA uses the North American Datum of 1983 (NAD 83) for all of its
>   charts. This datum is navigationally equivalent to the World Geodetic
>   System of 1984 (WGS 84).

I am not familiar with this concept. Could some one explain how the two datums are different, and how are they equivalent in terms of navigation?

Comment: I think it means you won't miss the harbor (or, more specifically, the navigation aids at the mouth of the harbor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it means the differences between the two datums are not significant enough to be a difference in Nautical Navigation.  Distance and Direction are so close as to be almost identical as far as Nautical Navigation is concerened

Comment: as to the differences if i remember correctly it comes out to about a 3 foot differences.  you can see http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=740  or http://www.uvm.edu/giv/resources/WGS84_NAD83.pdf